# How do I use LuaTex in MikTeX?

Tags: miktex, luatex, texworks

I am using MikTeX 2.9 version and although the manual says I can use LuaTeX, there is nothing in the TeXworks menu. I can see all the other members of the TeX family but none for LuaTeX.

Can someone point me as to how to configure it? I am using Windows Vista.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open TeXworks, choose `Edit -> Preferences...` in the menu and go to the `Typesetting` tab. In the `Processing tools` section, click on the little `+` button to add a new entry. In the dialog window, you have to type in the following values:

[image]

Repeat this step to add `LuaLaTeX`:

[image]

Now, you will be able to choose `LuaTeX`/`LuaLaTeX` from the dropdown box next to the green button.

**UPDATE**
In some cases, the argument `-synctex=1` may cause trouble. Try replacing it by `$synctexoption` in this case or leave it out completely.

Answer (score 4):

In preferences, composition, processing tools, you can add your preferred engines here in case luatex or lualatex ...
For Linux it's like that and also for os x I think for windows it's the same.
You can see the command line for others engines, and  after you can adapt for luatex and windows. 
First the command line ( /home/yourname/TeXLive/bin/i386-linux/luatex) then options, $synctexoption (to sync with the pdf) and $fullname.

you can add also

`%!TEX TS-program = lualatex` before your code !

Comment: @alif I don't know if my terms are exact because I use french version

Comment: Adding the `%!TEX ...` line only works if `TeXworks` has been configured to use `Lua(La)TeX` before, as described in the first part of your answer.

Comment: Ok! I have always seen  $synctexoption and not --synctex=1 like in texshop is it possible to use $synctexoption ?

Comment: It should also be possible to use `$synctexoption` - it differs from configuration to configuration and I've seen both possibilities. I updated my answer to include this.